# Ionic2 and Angular2 data binding using $event.target.value

Tags: angularjs, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a requirement to open a modal on click of input box. Modal contains list of countries with search bar, once modal is open it searches for text picked from input and shows filtered list. Now user can search for different country and select from filtered list, modal closes and value is added to input field. In code,

```
 openCountryPickerModal($event) {
          let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(CountryCodePickerComponent, {"searchValue":$event.target.value});

          modal.onDidDismiss(data => {
              if(data){
                 $event.target.value=data.countrySelected;
                 // Here: the value set to $event.target.value is not updating to input box's model emergencyContactInfo.currentPersonalAddress.country 
              }
          });          
          modal.present();
    }
```

and in template

```
<ion-input  (click)="openCountryPickerModal($event)"  [(ngModel)]="emergencyContactInfo.currentPersonalAddress.country"  type="text" placeholder="Country" readonly></ion-input>
```

Now the problem is, though it appears value is changed in UI, but never updates value to model. Any special reason?

I tried many ways to solve this but nothing works and I appreciate help if any.

Comment: i suggest you use [search bar](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/searchbar/Searchbar/)

Comment: Hi Suraj, the same is been used in modal, when modal opens it has search bar in header that filters list. if you click item, value is retuned to form using modal.onDidDismiss(data) method, which is then extracted and set to target input box.

Comment: Well since you already created a 2-way binding, why still use the `$event`? Just use `this.emergencyContactInfo.currentPersonalAddress.country` to prevent confusion

Comment: your `openCountryPickerModal` will not be called..it takes two parameters. what is `searchFor`? also you have `readonly`..

Comment: @Ivaro18 I have created a widget and this widget will be used in many places in a single form and also in other forms as well. So i cant use to set value to model as other inputs will have different medel

Comment: @Suraj searchFor i was in my dev copied from editor. corrected my post